# which document store for User defined filtering

Tags: json, database, nosql

We want to serve many homogeneous json documents for our frontend application. Each document belongs to one or more groups. The task is to deliver documents (ca 500k) of a given group. Each document has fifty properties which eventually will be used for filtering and sorting as the user selects. The result should be delivered with pagination.

At first we looked at mysql as it is our current used technology. There we can have a mapping table to the groups and dynamically build queries with where and order-by conditions on the fly.

Now we are considering couchdb as it sounds easier to scale and allows better handling of the documents which are in fact aggregations. However, as I made my first tests with views it feels harder to accomplish the same as in mysql. I understood we have to write dozens of views(?) upfront. Also I have difficulties to react on a user requests asking for products of a certain group which are filtered by field1 to value1(user input) and sorted by value2.

Here the query api of elastic search looks more straight forward to me. So the basic questions is: Which data store is for this type of application a good solution?